# JQuery using toggleClass and fadeTo

Tags: jquery, fadeto

I'm trying to do something that seems pretty simple, but its not working right. Maybe I'm making it too simple.

I will just write the pertinent code below.

I'm using bootstrap to create a button in my HTML. The class just makes the button white:

```
<button id="my_button" class="btn-default">Button</button>
```

Next I created a class in my CSS. It just makes an element transparent:

```
.select {opacity: 0.1;}
```

Finally, in JQuery I use the toggleClass and fadeTo functions to animate the button when it is clicked:

```
${'#my_button'}.toggleClass('btn-warning select').fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

The btn-warning class changes the color to yellow.

Here is what I'm expecting to happen:

1. On page load its just a plain white button
2. I click the button and it changes to yellow and the opacity changes
   to 10% then fades up to 100%
3. I click the button again and it just changes back to a plain white
   button
4. I click it again and it repeats step 2
5. so on and so forth

Seems simple enough. Step 1 works as expected, Step 2 is perfection, Step 3 excellent, Step 4... no dice

It only does the fadeTo on the first click, after that it changes to yellow, as it should, but no fadeTo effect.

Logically, I have my plain default button. I click it and JQuery will add the btn-warning and select classes to the button which turns it yellow and sets the opacity to 10%, then fade the opacity up to 100%. I click it again and JQuery removes the btn-warning class and select class, which turns the button back to its original form, the fadeTo has no effect because the opacity without the select class is already 100%.

That's all good, but when I click it again JQuery should add the two classes again and the

Comment: What is your question? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Please create a code snippet that shows what you are trying to do, and where you got to. It's had to understand it from your question

Comment: jQuery uses inline style to animate your fade animation. Maybe the inline style that manages the opacity is still present when you try step 4.
The inline style will override the `.select {opacity: 0.1;}`.
This is just a guess, if you could provide a fiddle, then we could help you more.

Comment: Ok sorry. I'm not at my computer at the moment, but I will post more code when I am. In the meantime I'm basically just creating a toggle on a button. It starts white, then when I click, it turns yellow and the the opacity goes to 10% and fades up to 100%. When I click it a third time, it just turns whit again. On the fourth click it turn yellow with opacity of 10% and fades in to 100%. The fourth click turns yellow, but doesn't fade it like the second click does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the opacity to 0.1 and replicate fadeTo using animate method

```js
var myBtn = $('#my_button');
$(myBtn).click (function () {
  $(myBtn).toggleClass('btn-warning');
  if ($(myBtn).hasClass ("btn-warning")) {
    $(myBtn).css ({opacity: 0.1}); 
    $(myBtn).animate ({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);  
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="my_button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Button</button>
```